# Using SQL tables with the same name on different schemas

Tags: sql, database, schema

Does anyone know of available white papers discussing the use of tables with the same name existing on different schemas?

I'm implementing on SQL Server but I imagine the theory can be applied to any RDBMS.

To be a little more specific, say I have a db that serves two applications and there's some crossover of resources between applications but some datasets are stored on separate schemas.

For example

```
App1.tblSomeData

App2.tblSomeData
```

What are the advantages/disadvantages of using the same name for both tables? The other alternative is to use different names:

```
App1.tblSomeDataForApp1

App2.tblSomeDataForApp2
```

This insures that all table names are unique, but does this have advantages/disadvantages?

Comment: @joe - the edit you made was helpful, but it missed  a few things and there's no need to add words like 'edit' into questions.  (Use the edit summary instead to record changes)

Comment: I don't know what you mean I missed some things; I literally took the text from his 'answer' and copied it into the question. Added 'edit' since I didn't want to re-word his question completely and so other users would understand there was a progression. (It's clearer for casual users who don't want to wade through edit history; "was the first answer for revision 2 or 15? hard to tell now because there are references to edited-out text". Alas, everyone has their own opinion on how edits should be made and consumed, and all of this is 100% off-topic ;)).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any white papers on this issue, probably because its not a complex enough subject to warrant an entire whitepaper.

If you fully qualify your table names every time you use them (`report.Customers` or `web.Customers` instead of just `Customers`), then you shouldn't have any problems, even if you do have the same table name in more than one schema. You should be doing this anyway, because its a performance optimization (SQL doesn't have to work to resolve ambiguous names).

I would highly recommend *not* relying on the user's "default schema" to determine *which* table is being selected. That just leads to trouble when the same code is called by users that have different default schemas.

Answer (score 1):

RDMSs will accept 'absolute' references to other tables and schemas in queries:

```
SELECT databasename.tablename.fieldname
FROM databasename.tablename
WHERE otherdatabase.othertable = ...
```

without any complaints. I don't know why someone would want to write up a white paper about this, as it'd be the equivalent of writing up a paper on how some people in different cities can have the same name ("Woah, did you know there's a John Smith in New York *AND* in Los Angeles?!?!?").

Comment: Ok, maybe I should make my question a little more specific. Say I have a db that serves two applications and there's some cross over of resources between applicatons but some datasets are stored on seperate schemas.

Comment: Then you do as the example query in my answer it. `select schema1.tablename.field, schema2.tablename.field`. You can use the db.table.field type notation anywhere a field name would go.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use multiple schemas, you have to qualify your object names with `schema.objectname`.  If you do not, SQL will assume the object you are calling is in the `dbo` schema.  If it doesn't find it there, it will error out.  If an object with the same name occurs in both `dbo` and another schema, you could end up selecting the wrong object if you do not fully qualify it.